# YA Layer model_20 expects 2 input(s), but it received 3 input tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am using Google Colab for training a CNN model on Images.

I have been using TF for a long time (version 2.1), but on Colab an assuming newer version of TF are installed.

WHile training my model, I encountered this:

```
    ValueError: Layer model_23 expects 2 input(s), but it received 3 input tensors. Inputs received:
 [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, None) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None, None) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:2' shape=(None, None) dtype=float32>]
```

Now I have encountered this error before, and I usually deal with this by enforcing any `2.x` TF version, as it generally doesn't care if the validation_data is in `tuple` or a `list` (as per my understanding that is), but this was not helpful at all.

Then I tried to convert all my lists into a tuple, and yet em encountering the same error for some reason.

I have not pasted the whole code here although here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/vybhav72954/187ab5fde841584756b6c5bcc1ee2fa6.js).

I have posted the code snippet below:

```py
print('Dataset: ', len(train_imgs))
print('Descriptions: train=', len(train_descriptions))
print('Photos: train=', len(train_features))
print('Vocabulary Size:', vocab_size)
print('Description Length: ', max_length)

model = define_model(vocab_size, max_length)
epochs = 10
steps = len(train_descriptions)
# making a directory models to save our models
os.mkdir("models")
for i in range(epochs):
    generator = data_generator(train_descriptions, train_features, tokenizer, max_length)
    model.fit(generator, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch= steps, verbose=1)
    model.save("models/model_" + str(i) + ".h5")
```

I will encourage people to go through the gist for the whole code.

EDIT: by making this change

```
    model.fit(generator, epochs=0, steps_per_epoch= steps, verbose=1)
```

Although I know this is not important, but I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: Link to the gist is it working? Provide correct gist link. Thanks!

Comment: Am sorry, i will update the link. @TFer